# What is the best approach to update/consolidate nuget packages targeting multiple frameworks?

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget-package, .net-standard, nuget-package-restore

I'm currently in the process of updating/consolidating nuget packages for our solutions.

**A quick background**

- Our projects are implemented in .NetFramework 4.6.2, .NETCore and .NETStandard.
- Our internal nuget packages are built mainly in Core with support for the above and referenced across projects

**The problem**

- As our solutions/projects grow we want to be on top of them and maintain consistency in the longer term and on the short-medium term we want to get rid of warnings & mismatches in package versions.

**The challenge**

- There is a hard dependency that we know of Newtonsoft.json = 9.0.0.1 because of some Microsoft Azure references we use.
- There are also some dependencies around System.Net.Http having a hard dependency on some 3rd Party libs we use with a lower version tightly coupled with Newtonsoft.json = 9.0.0.1.

**The goal**

- Although we have no control over how 3rdParties decide to implement their libs, we want to make sure that we take the best approach to how we implement ours and expose minimum version conflicts as a result.
- Also, we want to bring a standard on how these package updates should be conducted and which versions we aim to target/support.

**The question**:)

- What would be the best approach to achieve this? How do you do this?

Comment: This is how Microsoft unifies package versions (not really UI friendly, but it works):
.props file with the versions: [Packages.props](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/0c62bae6aade582227232183540fd891254a76cb/build/Targets/Packages.props/build/Targets/Packages.props); Example use: [CSharpVisualStudio.csproj](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/0c62bae6aade582227232183540fd891254a76cb/src/VisualStudio/CSharp/Impl/CSharpVisualStudio.csproj#L46)

Comment: Although not a direct answer, [read this](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/481) if you haven't already.  For me, it was a great help in understanding the way this area has been changing.